# Can a DNS record have a multi-level name?

Tags: dns

For a domain example.com, it is normal to have a record as follows:

```
blog IN CNAME www.example.com
```

Is this also allowed?

```
alex.blog IN CNAME www.example.com
```

Or, is it that there should be an NS record delegating the subdomain blog.example.com that can in turn have a record such as:

```
alex IN CNAME www.example.com
```

If it is possible, could someone also point me to an RFC/online-resource where I can read more.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible, and extremely common in the `in-addr.arpa.` and `ip6.arpa.` subtrees. I don't think there's an RFC that discusses it directly, it just falls out naturally from all other rules. You only need the NS and SOA records when delegating control of a subtree to someone else (or yourself, just because you want to treat it as separate).